# How do I know what user my ADO pipeline is using?

Tags: sql, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps pipelines, and have a PowerShell task that runs stuff with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. The PowerShell works fine when run from my computer, but when it runs through the pipeline it says it can't find or doesn't have access to the server. I don't see anything in the failed connection logs on my sql servers...

I assume whatever account the pipeline is attempting to connect under does not have access. How can I find out what that account is?

If you're curious, here's the simple PS, it just updates a table:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "myremoteserver" -Query "--update the table"
```

Comment: *I assume whatever account the pipeline is attempting to connect under does not have access* Not sure that is a safe assumption, especially since you’re not seeing failed connection attempts in the logs. Are you sure you have basic network connectivity?

Comment: @JohnWu From my computer, yes. I can ping and RDP into the server. Also access through SSMS. The PowerShell also runs on my computer against the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a powershell task to run below script to get the current user account that your pipeline is using

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

[image]